# std::thread access to a function loaded from a shared library

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-libraries, dlopen

On Ubuntu, I have a shared library `mylibrary.so`, with a function `AlphaFunction`. I want to load this function in C++ using `dlopen`, and then call it in two different threads. However, this is giving me run-time errors, presumably because the two threads are both trying to access the same memory where the function is stored.

The library itself controls a robot arm via USB, and the actual run-time error I get is: `LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE returned by the Write operation.`

I know how to use `std::atomic` for dealing with shared variables, but what about a shared function?

For example:

```
void Foo(int (*FooFunction)())
{
    while(true)
    {
        FooFunction();
    }
}

void Bar(int (*BarFunction)())
{
    while(true)
    {
        BarFunction();
    }
}


int main()
{
    void* api_handle = dlopen("mylibrary.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
    int (*MoveRobot)() = (int (*)()) dlsym(api_handle, "Move");

    std::thread t1(Foo, MoveRobot);
    std::thread t2(Bar, MoveRobot);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not defined `MoveRobot` with `extern "C"`.  If you are using a C++ compiler it has been name mangled.  See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html#externC

Comment: May not work depending on the internals of `MoveRobot` so I'm not pitching this as an answer, but have you tried restricting access to the function by wrapping the calls to `FooFunction` and `BarFunction` with `std::mutex?`

Comment: @jnbbender Who care's about `MoveRobot`, its an automatic var iin `main()`. I think you meant `Move` in the `mylibrary.so` library.

Comment: @WhozCraig My apologies

Comment: It wouldn't be due to accessing the "same memory where the function is stored" It would be because their IO function is not designed for concurrent execution. Or perhaps both callers do not have a proper setup of parameters that we can't see because this isn't the actual code. Regardless, invoking the same *function* concurrently is no different via dynaload than it is via local-definition. The caller and/or the callee are responsible for managing concurrency to *invoking* the function. If they don't do it and don't support it, *you have to*....

Comment: ... and even then, pray they don't store anything in TLS for "state" (which I doubt they do but never say never). if so, you have no choice but to marshall everything through the same *thread*.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at the comments. Here's a solution that covers all concerns:

- the robot library is not thread safe, and
- all calls to the robot library must be on the same thread

This answer proposes a solution in which a third thread is started up which acts as the robot request marshaller. The other threads post tasks to this thread's queue, which are executed one at a time, with the result of the call being returned via a future on which the caller can wait.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

// these definitions here just to make the example compile
#define RTLD_NOW 1
#define RTLD_GLOBAL 2
extern "C" void* dlopen(const char*, int);
extern "C" void* dlsym(void*, const char*);


struct RobotCaller final
{
    RobotCaller()
    {
        _library_handle = dlopen("mylibrary.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
        _Move = (int (*)()) dlsym(_library_handle, "Move");

        // caution - thread starts. do not derive from this class
        start();
    }

    void start()
    {
        _robot_thread = std::thread([this]{
            consume_queue();
        });
    }

    ~RobotCaller() {
        if (_robot_thread.joinable()) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
            _should_quit = true;
            lock.unlock();
            _queue_condition.notify_all();
            _robot_thread.join();
        }

        // close library code goes here
    }

    std::future<int> Move()
    {
        return queue_task(_Move);
    }

private:
    void consume_queue() {
        ;
        for(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex) ; !_should_quit ; lock.lock()) {
            _queue_condition.wait(lock, [this]{
                return _should_quit || (!_task_queue.empty());
            });

            if (!_task_queue.empty()) {
                auto task = std::move(_task_queue.front());
                _task_queue.pop();
                lock.unlock();
                task();
            }
        }
    }

    std::future<int> queue_task(int (*f)())
    {
        std::packaged_task<int()> task(f);
        auto fut = task.get_future();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mutex);
        _task_queue.push(std::move(task));
        return fut;
    }

private:
    // library management
    void* _library_handle = nullptr;
    int (*_Move)() = nullptr;

    // queue management
    std::thread _robot_thread;
    std::queue<std::packaged_task<int()>> _task_queue;
    bool _should_quit = false;
    std::mutex _queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable _queue_condition;
};

void Foo(std::function<std::future<int>()> FooFunction)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // marshal the call onto the robot queue and wait for a result
        auto result = FooFunction().get();
    }
}

void Bar(std::function<std::future<int>()> BarFunction)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // marshal the call onto the robot queue and wait for a result
        auto result = BarFunction().get();
    }
}


int main()
{
    RobotCaller robot_caller;

    std::thread t1(Foo, std::bind(&RobotCaller::Move, &robot_caller));
    std::thread t2(Bar, std::bind(&RobotCaller::Move, &robot_caller));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```